# Use Apache Cascading in windows

Tags: eclipse, apache, cascading

I am starting to use Cascading library, but I search information and all is about cascading on linux... I have executed fine the Impatient examples in a ubuntu server.

But I want to develop and test my application using eclipse in windows...

Is that posssible?? How I can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear the "Impatient" examples helped out -

There are two concerns: (1) Windows and (2) Eclipse.

Hadoop runs in Java, and is primarily meant for running apps on clusters. You must be careful on Windows, because the Java support is problematic. I've seen many students attempt to use Cygwin, thinking that would provide a Java layer -- it does not. Running Hadoop atop Cygwin typically is more trouble than it's worth. Obviously the [HDInsight](https://www.hadooponazure.com/) work by Microsoft is a great way to run Hadoop on Windows, on Azure.  To run Hadoop on your desktop Windows, it's best to use a virtual machine. Then be certain to run in "Standalone Mode", instead of pseudo-distributed mode or attempting to create a cluster on your desktop. Otherwise, it'd be better to run Cascading apps in HDInsight for Hadoop on Azure.

Eclipse is a much simpler answer. Gradle build scripts in for the "Impatient" series show how to use "gradle eclipse" to generate a project to import into your IDE. Even so, you may have to clean up some paths -- Eclipse doesn't handle Gradle imports as cleanly as it should, from what I've seen.

Hope that helps -

Answer (score 0):

To develop and test your Cascading application using eclipse in windows, you need to apply a patch (https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win). Download the patch jar, then add to your application's CLASSPATH. In your code, you need to set the properties "fs.file.impl"

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, Main.class);
if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") >= 0) {
  properties.put("fs.file.impl",
  "com.conga.services.hadoop.patch.HADOOP_7682.WinLocalFileSystem");
}
HadoopFlowConnector flowConnector = new HadoopFlowConnector(properties);
```